# sqlite3 Extracting BLOB data to text

Tags: text, encoding, sed, sqlite, blob

I'm trying to archive an old chat history from an instant messenger which is using a sqlite3 database to store all messages.

I can already read every message using the query

```
select out,data from messages order by mid DESC;
```

and sort it correctly but the problem is, that they are stored as BLOB. So the output looks something like this:

```
0|�j�"�}��ҟm�����7�y��ur�h\�S▒-message here-
0|�j�"�}��ҟm�����7�y��ur�h\�S▒-message here-
1|�j�"�|����m���ҟ�ur��ur��ZT-message here-
```

Can I somehow just extract this as text WITHOUT these nasty signs at the beginning? I can remove the question marks with sed, but the layout is still to bad.

Comment: What is the output of `hex(data)` for an example message?

Comment: it looks like this `BA6AEB221EACFCFFC1B2D1016DBCB19D03D29F02B5757299B5757299440BA65309776965736F3F20784400002063ED3D00000000`

Comment: If the header has a fixed size, use [substr](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr).

Comment: seems like the header is always 66 hex digits, how can I use substr to skip the first 66 hex digits from "data" in this query? `select out,hex(data) from messages order by mid DESC;`
already thanks for your awesome help guys!

Comment: That would be 33 bytes. Ignore `hex`; read the help I linked to.